# structures, inheritance and definition

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, definition, structure

i need to help with structures, inheritance and definition.

```
//define struct
struct tStruct1{
    int a;
};

//definition
tStruct1 struct1{1};
```

and inheritance

```
struct tStruct2:tStruct1{
    int b;
};
```

How can I define it in declaration line?

```
tStruct2 struct2{ ????? };
```

One more question, how can i use inheritance for structures defined with typedef struct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, the `typedef` for a structure doesn't change anything, it only introduces an alternative name for the type. You can still inherit from it as usual.

The `Type identifier{params}` syntax for definitions is C++0x syntax for the new [uniform initialization](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#uniform-init). In pre-C++0x you have two choices for initialization of user-defined types.

**Aggregate Initialization**

Aggregates are [POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) types and arrays of PODs or built-in types. They can be initialized using initializer lists with curly braces:

```
struct A {
    int i;
};
struct B {
    A j;
    int k;
};

B b = {{1}, 2 };
```

This is covered in more detail in this [InformIT article](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=171).

As noted this only works for POD-types and thus doesn't work when inheritance comes into play. In that case you have to use

**User-defined constructors**

They allow you to initialize your custom types rather freely by defining special member functions:

```
struct A {
    int i;
    A(int number) : i(number) {}
};
struct B : A {
    int j;
    B(int number1, number2) : A(number1), j(number2) {}
};

B b(1, 2);
```

Constructors are covered in more detail in [this InformIT article](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=15).